# numerical order of loops in R

Tags: r

I've got a loop which acts upon a list like

```
files_list = list.files("/home", pattern = "*txt", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)

for (i in seq_along(files_list)) {

        do something etc
}
```

The files are in the 'correct' order in my file browser in that they are

```
1_file.txt
2_file.txt
...
18_file.txt
```

But when the loop reads them in, it reads them in in this order:

```
10_file.txt
11_file.txt
12_file.txt
13_file.txt
14_file.txt
15_file.txt
16_file.txt
17_file.txt
18_file.txt
1_file.txt
2_file.txt
```

etc, which is annoying and screwing up my results print-out. Is there a way in which I can get the for loop to read in the files in the 'correct' numerical order, i.e. like in my directory, 1_file.txt, 2_file.txt etc.

thanks

Comment: Try with `mixedsort` i.e. `gtools::mixedsort(paste0(sample(1:10), "_file.txt"))`

Comment: `for( i in files_list ) { .... }` would give your desired order.

Comment: The files are in _alphabetical order_. One way that you can fix this is to name the files with 01_ instead of 1_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `list.files` and `dir` return the files in alphabetical order as mentioned in the comments above.  To generalize, what is the significance of the order of your files?  Do you want them ordered numerically by prefix?  Then try this:

```
ff <- dir(pattern=".txt")
ff <- ff[order(as.numeric(gsub("_.*", "", ff)))]
```

I see you use `full.names=T`.  If paths are included in your filenames, you will need to use basename:

```
 ff <- ff[order(as.numeric(gsub("_.*", "", basename(ff))))]
```

On the other hand, if they are named that way because that was the order they were created in you could also sort by time:

```
ff <- ff[order(sapply(ff, file.mtime), decreasing = FALSE)]
```

Then you can do

```
for(f in ff) {
  # do something with f
}
```

hth.